# Right translation is a continuous action for fixed $f\in L^2(G)$

Tags: continuity, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, and consider the space $L^2(G)$ with the Haar measure. For $f\in L^2(G)$, denote $L_gf$ by the map which sends $x$ to $f(xg)$. I want to show that the map
$$
g\mapsto L_gf
$$
for fixed $f\in L^2(G)$ is continuous. I was thinking of giving an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof (since I have a lack of experience in this topic). So I want to argue that if $g$ is close enough to some fixed $g_0$, then
$$
\int_G (L_gf-L_{g_0}f)^2<\epsilon.
$$
However, I'm not exactly sure how to tackle this, as we don't have continuity of $f$. Maybe there are some results I am unaware of, which could make this proof straightforward? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you defning the integral? Because (and it's the only one I know) if you consider $G$ to be a (compact) manifold and use Haar measure, the construction itself  gives you  $\int_G \ell_h\circ f=\int_G f$.

Comment: @Matematleta I had noticed that too, but we have a product here,
$$
\int_G (L_gf)^2-2\int_G L_gfL_{g_0}f+\int_G (L_{g_0}f)^2.
$$
I would think that $\int_G (L_gf)^2=\int_G f^2$ holds as well, which would mean we end up with
$$
2\int_G f^2-2\int_G L_gfL_{g_0}f=2\int_G(f^2- fL_{g^{-1}g_0}f).
$$
If this is correct, could I then maybe use Hölder's inequality?

Comment: I think we can do it using a density arguement  and the fact that the Haar measure is translation-invariant . Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is true in general for $1\le p\le \infty. $ We use the density of the continuous functions in $L^p(G)$ together with the translation invariance of the Haar measure, $\mu$:

Without loss of generality, $g_0=e.$  Take an $h\in C(G)$ such that $\|h-f\|_p<\epsilon.  
\ $ There is an open set $U\ni e$ such that $\|h(xg)-h(x)\|_p<\epsilon$ whenever $xgx^{-1}\in U.$ This is possible because $h$ is uniformly continuous  $^{*}$ and $\mu(G)=1.$ Then, we have

$\|f(xg)-f(x)\|_p=\|f(xg)-h(xg)+h(xg)-h(x)+h(x)-f(x)\|_p\leq\\ \|f(xg)-h(xg)\|_p+\|h(xg)-h(x)\|_p+\|h(x)-f(x)\|_p<3\varepsilon$

$^{*}$ Here is a sketch of the proof that $h$ is uniformly continuous:

$\underline{\text{Preliminaries}}$

$h: G\to \mathbb C$ is (left) uniformly continuous on $G$ if (and only if) for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $e$ such that $|h(g)-h(g')|<\epsilon$ for any $g,g'\in G$ such that $g^{-1}g'\in V.$ Equivalently,

$\tag1 |h(gv)-h(v)|<\epsilon\ \forall g\in G,v\in V$

The multiplication

$\tag2 \varphi:G\times G\to G:(g,g')\mapsto gg'$

is continuous, and

$\tag3\varphi_g:G\to G:g'\mapsto gg'$

is a homeomorphism for each $g\in G$ (in fact, if $G$ is a Lie group, then $\varphi_g$ is a diffeomorphism with respect to its manifold structure).

$\underline{\text{The proof}}$

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Using $(3)$, for each $g\in G$ there is a neighborhood $U_g\ni e$ such that $|h\circ \varphi_g(u)-h\circ \varphi_g(e)|=|h(gu)-h(ge)|=|h(gu)-h(g)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ as soon as $u\in U_g.$ Now, from $(2)$ it follows that there is a neighborhood $V_g\ni e$ such that

$\tag4  V_gV_g\subseteq U_g$

$G$ is compact, so there is a $\{g_i\}^n_{i=1}$ such that $G=\bigcup^n_{i=1} g_iV_{g_i}$. Set $V:=\bigcap^n_{i=1}V_{g_i}$, which is open and non-empty and suppose $g\in G.$ Then, from this and $(4)$, we have for some $1\le i \le n,$  $g\in g_iV_{g_i}\subseteq g_iU_{g_i}$ so $g=g_iu$ for some $u\in U_{g_i}$ and so

$\tag 5|h(g)-h(g_i)|=|h(g_iu)-h(g_i)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

And if $v\in V,$ then $gv\in g_iV_{g_i}V\subseteq g_iV_{g_i}V_{g_i}\subseteq g_iU_{g_i}$ so $gv=g_iu$ for some $u\in U_{g_i}$, which implies that

$\tag 6|h(gv)-h(g_i)|=|h(g_iu)-h(g_i)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

To finish, note that $(5)$ and $(6)$ combine to give $(1).$

Comment: I'm assuming that you use that $G$ is metrizable, in order to talk about uniform continuity? I don't see yet why $xgx^{-1}\in U$ implies that $\Vert h(xg)-h(x)\Vert_p$. I understand that we want to have $xg$ and $x$ close to each other, but I don't see how this conjugation gives us that. Also, why is $\mu(G)=1$ necessary?

Comment: I've just checked a couple of sources, and they all define uniform continuity for metric spaces. I am willing to use your definition, but I would like to ask: does your definition arise from the metrization of a top. group?

Also, I rather meant to ask why the finiteness of $\mu(G)$ was necessary. So we have now that $\vert h(xg)-h(x)\vert$ is small for $xgx^{-1}\in U$, but if we integrate over $G$, we don't necessarily have $xgx^{-1}\in U$, right? So how do we use this neighbourhood? I'm guessing this has something to do with the translation invariance of $\mu$, but I don't see how.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. If we have such a neighbourhoud $U$, and we take a $g\in U$, then for any $x\in G$, we have $x(g^{-1}x)^{-1}=g\in U$. Hence, $\vert f(x)-f(g^{-1}x)\vert<\epsilon$. Since taking the inverse is a continuous operation, we can find a neighbourhood which maps $y$ to $y^{-1}\in U$, and then the inequality follows.  I guess what is left to show for me is that if $h$ is continuous on a compact group $G$, then $h$ is uniformly continuous (using this definition). I might turn that into a new question if I don't figure it out, and I will consider this problem as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure we can find such neighbourhoods, since that would mean that $\vert h(g)-h(e)\vert<\epsilon$ for each $g$. However, I got helped in the chat, and I was hinted to look at $H\colon G\times G\to \mathbb R\colon (g,g')\mapsto h(g)-h(g')$ and $\phi\colon G\times G\to G\times G\colon (g,h)\mapsto (g,gh^{-1})$. Since $\phi(H^{-1}(-\epsilon,\epsilon))\supset G\times \{e\}$, it follows from the tube lemma there is a neighbourhood $U\ni e$, such that $gg'^{-1}\in U$ means $\vert h(g)-h(g')\vert<\epsilon$.

Comment: You're welcome! I am deleting my comments to get rid of the clutter.